# System.ExecutionEngineException in C++CLI

Tags: c, c++-cli, native

I have converted may native pointer to manged object via IntPtr in my Wrapper.cpp
Below is my code,

```
    _declspec(dllexport)int UnmanagedAlgebraComputation::SubtractMultiplyWrapper(UnmanagedSubtraction *unmanagedSubtraction)
     {
        AlgebraCSharp::AlgebraComputation^ obj= AlgebraCSharp::AlgebraComputation::GetObject;
        unmanagedSubtraction=new UnmanagedSubtraction();
        System::IntPtr ip=System::IntPtr(unmanagedSubtraction);
        Object^ handle=Marshal::GetObjectForIUnknown(ip) ; 
        return obj->Subtraction((AlgebraCSharp::SubtractComputation^)handle);
     }
```

But On the Line   Object^ handle=Marshal::GetObjectForIUnknown(ip) ; It throws the exception as **'System.ExecutionEngineException'** .
Please Let me know the solution related to this.

Comment: Well, this is not supposed to happen, quacks like a CLR bug.  But the odds that "ip" is in fact a valid IUnknown COM interface pointer are very close to zero if you create the unmanaged object with the *new* operator.  COM objects must be created with CoCreateInstance().  So just don't use GetObjectForIUnknown() to avoid the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause is that the marshalling tool does not know how to marshal your type.so may be you can try Nested structures in the struct by prefixing your struct as

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
```

or 
  prefixing Nested arrays like

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
```

you can  check this link http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System/types/ExecutionEngineException.html